# UNSUPPORTED_PAYEE_CURRENCY Paypal Response in Android?

Tags: android, paypal-sandbox

I am Getting response like this,why I had like this error ,I dont know why it is coming,Here is my Error Results

```
request failure with http statusCode:400,exception:org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Bad Request request failed with server response:{"name":"UNSUPPORTED_PAYEE_CURRENCY","details":[],"message":"The currency is not acceptedbypayee.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors","debug_id":"b5cb9cc041f7b"} UNSUPPORTED_PAYEE_CURRENCY
```

I just Logged in my pay pal account,and i transfer 1 dollar ,but getting error like this.Please tell suggestion

Comment: what is the request, Currency, INR is not supported in Paypal

Comment: thingToBuy = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("1.0"), "USD", "HeadSet", PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE); i just send like this